# File contains corrupted data - Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, webrtc, nuget-package, xsockets.net

I am trying to follow this [article](http://xsockets.net/blog/tutorial-building-a-multivideo-chat-with-webrtc). There is a step which says you need to install  `XSockets.Sample.WebRTC` via package manager console(`PMC`), this is where I got stuck. 
 I have been getting an error which says `File contains corrupted data`, shown as below -
 
[image]

I went through this [post](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/272453)
but none of the solutions worked for me. I could not find any solution to my problem. What am I doing wrong? How do I make it work?

Another question is, in the [article](http://xsockets.net/blog/tutorial-building-a-multivideo-chat-with-webrtc) that I am following, there is this picture which shows - 
[image]

but I got nothing like `LocalNuget` in my `package source`. I got only two options - check the above image.

Why is this difference? Is there anything wrong with my visual studio installation?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem was with `Nuget Package Manager Console`.If anyone comes across this problem, then try and update the `Nuget Package Manager` version, worked in my case.

To update `Nuget Package Manager` click on 
 `Tools` -> `Extensions and Updates` -> `Updates` 
  -> `Visual Studio Gallery` -> `Nuget Package Manager`.

Answer (score 2):

I updated Nuget Package Manager version to 2.8 (latest till date) but same issues.

Finally, referring to solutions at http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/272453 I got the problem resolved.

By clearing package cache and disabling antivirus temporarily  installation of XSockets.Sample.WebRTC via package manager console(PMC) was successful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Right click in the project -> Unload project
Then, right click in the .csproj and edit. Look for Xsockets.Sample.WebRTC (maybe is not there)

If it is there, remove it, and reinstall again after Load again the project ;)

Comment: .. mmmm, but there was the reference there in the .csproj?

Comment: Ok, and now, try to install the package, but not from the console, try from the Nuget Package manager

Comment: Right click in your solution -> Manage nuget packages for solution OR right click in your project -> Manage nuget packages ;)

Comment: I searched for `Xsocket.Sample.WebRTC`..but nothing came up.

Comment: Look for Xsocket and a lot of them appear. Then, you will need to check which one is what you need

Comment: `Xsocket.Sample.WebRTC` is the one that the article says to install, which is not showing up..What to do? Can we move this to a chatroom?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49219/discussion-between-aritra-b-and-oscar-bralo)

Comment: you are not getting the point..the problem is with installing the `Xsocket.Sample.WebRTC`, the article that you referred also says to install this!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after using powershell to do a solution wide string replace.  I wasn't careful to exclude .exe files from the command, and it altered the nuget.exe file in the .nuget folder. Upgrading Nuget Package Manager did not help, but replacing the nuget.exe with a version from another solution did.

An easy way to tell if this is your issue, is to run the suspect nuget.exe with a right-click, run as administrator and if it gives you an error that it's not compatible with your version of windows, than you know its busted.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error after recovering a solution the was deleted by mistake, solved the problem as following.
I closed visual studio then removed all packages from packages folder, when i opened the solution again the error message isn't there and VS asked me to restore missing packages, after restoring packages every thing is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this out of the blue.

I needed to update to Package Manager console Version 2.8.60723.765.

Starting it displayed:

```
========================
NuGet Enable Package Restore Fix
========================
To fix package restore:
1. Please enable package restore in Visual Studio FIRST.
2. Run the command: Install-NuGetEnablePackageRestoreFix 
3. Restart Visual Studio.

This should fix that pesky broken build you are experiencing.
```

Running

`Install-NuGetEnablePackageRestoreFix`

and Rebuilding fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

During a package restore, my PC lost power. I also had the issue with nuget package manager:

> File contains corrupted data

When I opened the Package Manager Console, I got this message:

> Unable to read package from path 'Microsoft.OData.Core.6.15.0\Microsoft.OData.Core.6.15.0.nupkg'.

I solved it by simply deleting that package from the disk and when I opened package manager, the original error message was gone and I was able to restore the package I had deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Nuget Package Manager extension was already the latest version & also clearing up local cache didn't help either.

However, when I cleared the packages folder & rebuilt the solution - it fixed the problem.